# Como puede hacer para cambiar el idioma del texto HTML que me sale en el formlario de UserCreationForm()

Tags: django, formularios, django-forms

He hecho un formulario de registro en Django con la función de UserCreationForm() que te lo crea automáticamente. Quería saber si se puede cambiar el idioma de ingles a español del texto que aparecen en el código HTML de la pagina, ya que como tal yo no tengo un HTML con ese código.

He intentado cambiar el idioma del HTML donde inicializo el form pero sigue sin funcionar.

Este es mi código hasta ahora:

Forms.py

```
class CustomUserForm(UserCreationForm):
     pass
```

Views.py

```
def registro_usuario(request):
data={
    "form": CustomUserForm()
}
if request.method == "POST":
    formulario = CustomUserForm(request.POST)
    if formulario.is_valid():
        formulario.save()
        username = formulario.cleaned_data["username"]
        password = formulario.cleaned_data["password1"]
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect(to='base')
return render(request, 'registration/register.html', data)
```

Urls.py

```
path('registro/', views.registro_usuario, name='registro_usuario'),
```

register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Registro</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Pagina de Registro</h1>
<form method= "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <table>
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </table>

    <input type="reset" value="Limpiar">
    <input type="submit" value="Registrar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

El HTML visualiza esto en el buscador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado en vídeos de youtube y a algunas personas se les cambia, he probado de todo pero sigo sin saber porque me sigue apareciendo en inglés. Toda ayuda es bien recibida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías editar el idioma que está definido en `LANGUAGE_CODE` de tu archivo `settings.py`, cambiarlo por el idioma de tu interés. Por ejemplo `'es-es'` (para España) o `'es-ar'` (para Argentina).

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-es' # para España
```

Acá podés ver la documentación oficial:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.2/ref/settings/#language-code